# Breezejs and type inheritance: a few questions

Tags: entity-framework, knockout.js, breeze

I use breeze with Entity Framework 6 Code First, C# Web Api 2 and Knockout.
Everything was rather fine until I added descendant type for one of my entity types. This resulted in broking behaviour on several parts of my app. The cause of problems:

1. now `entityManager.getEntityByKey('baseTypeName', id, true)` always returns entity of descendant type
2. extending base type with `baseEntityType.dataProperties.push(prop)` does not affect entities of descendant type

I decided to remove descendant type from metadata:

```
public class DbContextForBreezeMetadata : MyDbContext
{
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Ignore<DescendantType>();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
  }
}

public class EntityContextProvider : EFContextProvider<MyDbContext>
{
  protected override string BuildJsonMetadata()
  {
    return new EFContextProvider<DbContextForBreezeMetadata>().Metadata();
  }
}
```

After doing that I saw that all properties of base entities became dependentObservables.

So, the questions: is it a way to get breeze to work with such entities as if they are of not related types? How to change metadata (removing descendant type) so that base entities would have observables but not dependentObservables as properties?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the DocCode sample in the breeze.js.samples repo.  The are several examples of  inheritance models there using EF.

Comment: You are ignoring questions itself, does it mean that this behaiviour is not standart and is result of my app configuration?